# How to send jmeter test results to datadog?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, datadog

I wanted to ask if anyone has ever saved jmeter test results (sampler names, duration, pass/fail) to Datadog? Kinda like the backend listener for influx/graphite... but for Datadog. Jmeter-plugins has no such plugin. Datadog seems to offer something called "JMX integration" but I'm not sure whether that is what I need.

Comment: I think at this moment... this is probably the best way to go https://docs.datadoghq.com/api/?lang=bash#post-an-event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out how to do this using the datadog api https://docs.datadoghq.com/api/?lang=python#post-timeseries-points. The following python script takes in the jtl file (jmeter results) and posts the transaction name, response time, and status (pass/fail) to datadog.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
import pandas as pd
from datadog import initialize, api

options = {
    'api_key': '<API_KEY>',
    'app_key': '<APPLICATION_KEY>'
}
metrics = []

def get_current_metric(timestamp, label, elapsed, success):
    metric = {}
    metric.update({'metric': 'jmeter'})
    metric.update({'points': [(timestamp, elapsed)]})
    curtags = {}
    curtags.update({'testcase': label})
    curtags.update({'success': success})
    metric.update({'tags': curtags})
    return metric

initialize(**options)

jtl_file = sys.argv[1]
df = pd.read_csv(jtl_file)

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    timestamp = row['timeStamp']/1000
    label = row['label']
    elapsed = row['elapsed']
    success = str(row['success'])
    metric = get_current_metric(timestamp, label, elapsed, success)
    metrics.append(metric)

api.Metric.send(metrics)
```